# Schematic for pulse generator by Terence Thomas

Tags: oscillator, schematics

#### TL;DR

Does anyone have the schematic for pulse generator by Terence Thomas, as described in Chapter 2 of his book Sound Synthesis (ISBN 9780830692767))?

---

I am trying to build the sequencer, on page 58 from chapter 6 of the same book, the [schematic](http://electro-music.com/forum/phpbb-files/seq2_226.jpg) of which I found here on [this post](http://electro-music.com/forum/post-141185.html#141185), of the thread, [simple 8 step sequecer for SL](http://electro-music.com/forum/topic-7338-125.html) (the mis-spelling/typo in the title is intentional).

[image: Programmable sequencer schematic - Terence Thomas]

The [following page (page 60)](http://electro-music.com/forum/phpbb-files/seq3_104.jpg), describes the oscillator used to provide a clock signal to the sequencer:

> The sequencer used together with the pulse generator (described in chapter 2) form a unique control facility

I have searched for over a week now, and whilst I have a general idea of the circuit, I am missing a few details<sup>1</sup>.

From a post, on [Buchla 144 dual square wave oscillator DIY](https://www.muffwiggler.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=129190&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=25&sid=347ce140ac52beeb812ebb05b6305168), it appears that the pulse generator referred to is a UJT relaxation oscillator:

> This is a “Terrence Thomas” build, from his book, from years ago, that is very similar to a Buchla, but has a 2N2646 saw-relaxation oscillator and a TL071-schmitt trigger (square-wave), with a 2N2222, for pulse modulation. The book calls for a 741, which does not work for crap, with the poor slew-rate and overall bad performance. It is a really quirky oscillator.

So I now know that it is a UJT relaxation oscillator, most probably very similar to that which Terence Thomas has posted in [Unusual Components and Applications](http://www.electricalfun.com/workbenchfun/unusual_components_tthomas.aspx)
by Terence Thomas (Negisters, Unijunction transistors, Precision Resistors, and Hall Effect Devices):

[image: UJT relaxation oscillator]

However, some components (NOR gate, S2, S3, R5 and C7), which are referenced in Chapter 6, on page 60 are missing

> Switch S3, on the pulse clock, provides access to the pulse output
> when it is in the up position, but in the down position (as in the
> pulse clock schematic), a single pulse mode engages. This mode of
> operation allows the user to advance the sequencer just one stage. A
> closer look at the pulse clock schematic shows that one section of the
> quad NOR gate, combined with switch S2, resister R5 and capacitor C7,
> form a bounceless switch. When switch S2 is pressed, the sequencer
> advances one stage only, to facilitate easy tuning.

I *could* order the entire book from an online retailer, even though I only need one schematic from it, but it will take over a month to arrive, as I do not reside in the US. I have checked with my local area library/libraries, and second hand retailers, and they do not have the book available. There is not an e-book/PDF version of the book either.

Does anyone have a scan of the actual schematic, from chapter 2 of the book, or a re-created schematic in Eagle? Or even a complete schematic of the sequencer including the clock circuit, with the single step circuitry?

Yes, I could use any oscillator/clock circuit, but I would like to follow Thomas's original plan.

---

<sup>1</sup> I found some addition information on these two posts ([1](https://forum.moogmusic.com/viewtopic.php?p=30242&sid=be7ef036fe235770962e7b0afaf26292#p30242) and [2](https://forum.moogmusic.com/viewtopic.php?p=30410&sid=be7ef036fe235770962e7b0afaf26292#p30410)), from [Analog Sequencer](https://forum.moogmusic.com/viewtopic.php?q=forum/viewtopic.php&p=30375). However, the schematic of the oscillator, although promised, was never posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I purchased the book, and got hold of the schematic:

[image: Voltage-controlled pulse generator schematic]

I have also made an Eagle schematic, [TT_PulseGen_V1.0.sch](https://github.com/greenonline/Terence-Thomas).